# Imagepicker doesn't appear as block

Tags: 7, views, media

I would like the [Image Picker](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagepicker) to be available on a node (page) as a block so that users can upload images without clicking on 'edit' where they can edit the actual page itself.

I have definitely enabled the setting in the configuration:
[image]

Do I need to do it via the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module (which I do have installed also)?

Answer (score 0):

U want a block for image picker, I have checked it and found that it creates iframe for the same. so what we can do, is create a block either programmatically or manually and alter its content, by using hook_block_view_alter, and load image picker in it, and hide rest of element in drupal 7.